# Regarding the tag: submission

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

I suggest that the 20 questions with tag [submission](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/submission) be retagged as necessary and the tag itself deleted. Some are properly tagged with paper-submission or other tags that already seem to be sufficient.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any [conference-submission] tag, is it a typo in the question?

Comment: @GoodDeeds, no, just bad memory. I was looking at a lot of tags. I'll fix.

Comment: I updated the five closed or duplicate question. There are now 15 open questions.

Comment: Should we make [tag:submission] a synonym of [tag:paper-submission]?

Comment: Your call. Check all the posts first. I’m offline for the night. Maybe a few adjustments needed.

Comment: @cag51 I stripped the tag from a few questions asked more than a year ago. I'll continue to strip unless you suggest I not. I won't do too many at once to avoid messing up the queue too much. Now down to eleven, I think. tag paper-submission works for all the remains ones and is already there on many of them.

Comment: I just proposed [tag:submission] as a synonym for [tag:paper-submission]. Four votes are required. This is the first time I've tried this. See the synonym link on the latter tag if you have enough rep to vote.

Comment: Catching up on this....looks good to me, I hammered the synonym through.

Comment: @cag51 looks good. I just finished cleaning up guaranteed-admission. See if it works. Maybe I'll add a bit to the wiki about "open admissions" for grad school.

Comment: This question is probably now status-completed.